# Virtual Host APACHE ssl

Tags: ubuntu, apache, ssl, virtualhost

Tengo un problema al activar a2enmod ssl

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

** He revisado mi virtual host y al parecer está bien **

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `systemctl status apache2.service` que cuenta? ahí tendría que marcar el file y linea del error

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, 
 AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/ports.conf: 
Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port  

actualizo con mi archivo ports.conf

Comment: edite un poco el formato, mepa que se comió los saltos de línea. el problema puede ser que el primer `Listen 443` choque con los siguientes condicionales ( los de `IfModule` ). lo mas común es mas simple: al hacer un restart se mantienen abiertos los puertos de la config anterior y si cambiaron entran en conflicto si estan duplicados, ahi lo que hay que hacer es un stop y start

Comment: linea 9 con los saltos de linea me parece que cae en el segundo listen y como ahora esta el modulo enabled ( ssl_module ) trata de bindear el mismo puerto de la línea 6 (?)

Comment: Perfecto, he dejado una imagen de como se ve mi archivo ports.conf